# Alterar tipo de dado varchar para int

Tags: mysql, sql, query, int, varchar

Existe algum problema em alterar o tipo de dado de varchar para int no mysql?
Eu possuo uma planilha com alguns itens que foram inseridos como varchar, todos são números. O problema é que eu preciso fazer uma busca de maior e menor, porém, como está em varchar eu não sei se funciona. Além disso, tenho receio de alterar o tipo e ter perda nos dados.

Comment: Se fizer tudo corretinho não precisa ter medo, só mantenha o campo varchar e crie um novo com int

Comment: da para usar a função CAST ou rodar um script em PHP, Java, ou outra linguagem para inserir no novo campo

Comment: Você pode tentar o [CONVERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html)

Comment: como @sveen falou, não precisava de nada, bastou atualizar o campo. Todos os dados mantidos.